# How can i get all field names from document in xpage using SSJS?

Tags: xpages

How can i get all field names from document in xpage using `SSJS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richard,
a document doesn't have fields, it has items. So you either want all fields in the form mentioned in the form item or all items (or all items that are also fields in the form?). Standard notes mechanism applies:

```
var doc = currentDocument.getDocument();
var curItem;
var allItems = doc.getItems(); // That's a vector of NotesItesm
for (var i = 0; i < allItems.size(); i++) {
    curItem = items.elementAt(i);
    print curItem.getName();
    curItem.recycle();
}
doc.recycle();
```

Similar approach for forms: get the `form` item and then do a `database.getForm(formName)` and iterate through the fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
var doc:NotesDocument = database.getAllDocuments().getFirstDocument();
var itemNames:java.util.Vector = new java.util.Vector();

var items:java.util.Iterator = doc.getItems().iterator();
var item:NotesItem;
while( items.hasNext() ){
    item = items.next();
    itemNames.add( item.getName() );
    item.recycle();
}

doc.recycle();
```

Then all field names are in the Vector *itemNames*.

Comment: Short of ignoring the (current) "document in xpages" part of the question I think the iterator should work better than the elementAt :-)